# Radius of Convergence for this Power Series

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the radius of convergence of the following power series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^{a_k}$$

where $$a_k = \begin{cases}
k & : k \text{ is prime}\\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Any help is appreciated - thank you!

Comment: So you can write $\displaystyle \sum_{p\text{ prime}} px^p.$ That seems a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy-Hadamard:

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{p\to\infty}\sqrt[p]{a_p}=1$$

Comment: That should suffice.  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\limsup_{k\to\infty} |a_k|^{\frac {1}{k}}=$$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} e^{\frac {\ln (k)}{k}}=1$$

$$\implies R=1$$